# The configuration registry key could not be opened (0x800703F3) - SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

While i was trying to install Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, i encountered an error which is called 'impossible to open registry configuration key (0x800703F3)'.

It gives me a log with the output of the error:

```
> [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i000:
> MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall
> progress: 3 [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]e000: Error 0x800703f3:
> Process returned error: 0x3f3 [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]e000:
> Error 0x800703f3: Failed to execute EXE package.
> [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]e000: Error 0x800703f3: Failed to
> configure per-machine EXE package.
> [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction:
> Install Completed for package SQL Server Analysis Services (id:
> Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices)
> [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i319: Applied execute package:
> Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, result: 0x800703f3, restart:
> None [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]e000: Error 0x800703f3: Failed to
> execute EXE package. [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i329: Removed
> package dependency provider: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices,
> package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices
> [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i351: Removing cached package:
> Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, from path:
> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\
> [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i000:
> MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall
> progress: 100 [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i372: Session end,
> registration key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{b5f086b7-5c95-4c1a-887b-f129b60d1f3b},
> resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
> [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i330: Removed bundle dependency
> provider: {b5f086b7-5c95-4c1a-887b-f129b60d1f3b}
> [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i352: Removing cached bundle:
> {b5f086b7-5c95-4c1a-887b-f129b60d1f3b}, from path:
> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{b5f086b7-5c95-4c1a-887b-f129b60d1f3b}\
> [1830:047C][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i371: Updating session, registration
> key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{b5f086b7-5c95-4c1a-887b-f129b60d1f3b},
> resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
> [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction:
> Bundle action failed: Impossível abrir a chave de registo da
> configuração (0x800703F3) [0664:26A0][2018-05-09T03:16:16]i399: Apply
> complete, result: 0x800703f3, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
> [0664:29B4][2018-05-09T03:21:56]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening
> url:
> C:\Users\LUSALM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-PTB_20180509031104.log
> [0664:29B4][2018-05-09T03:23:57]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening
> url:
> C:\Users\LUSALM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-PTB_20180509031104.log
```

Any help is highly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as no one know the answer for this, it seems that someone have found a solution here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html

> "Michael Mallit [MSFT] ·  The versions should be
>   1.15.3227. So please uninstall any VS instances, then uninstall the VS Installer through Add/Remove programs and verify C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer is removed and/or empty.
>
> Thanks, Mike"